# Position of a node within a nodeList, XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

If I have two `NodeList`s where one list is a subset of the other, is there a way I can compare the lists to determine the position within the full `NodeList` of all the nodes in the subset `NodeList`? For example, given the following XML:

```
<Bill domain="QBO" sparse="false">
    <Line>
        <AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
            1
        </AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
    </Line>
</Bill>
<Bill domain="QBO" sparse="false">
    <Id>148</Id>
    <Line>
        <AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
            1
        </AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
    </Line>
</Bill>
```

Evaluating `Bill/Line` would return a `NodeList` with two nodes. `Bill[Id]/Line`would return a `NodeList` with one node. How can I find the position of the single `Node` from the second `NodeList`within the first `NodeList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
count((//Bill[Id])[1]/preceding-sibling::Bill[Line])
```

will start at the first `Bill` element in the document with an `Id` child element (`(//Bill[Id])[1]`) and count the number of *preceding sibling* `Bill` elements that have `Line` child element.